# Definedness of pointer-integer casts

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

I am interested in the definedness (undefinedness, implementation-definedness) of casts from pointers to integers and various related operations. Mostly I am interested in C11, but answers for other standard versions (or even C++) are welcome.

For the purposes of this question, assume that the C implementation provides `intptr_t`.

Consider the following functions:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int x;
int y;
int z[2];

void f1(void) {
    int *p = &x;
    intptr_t i = p;
}

void f2(void) {
    int *p = &x;
    intptr_t i1 = p;
    intptr_t i2 = p;
    assert(i1 == i2);
}

void f3(void) {
    int *p1 = &x;
    int *p2 = &y;
    intptr_t i1 = p1;
    intptr_t i2 = p2;
    assert(i1 != i2);
}

void f4(void) {
    int *p1 = &x;
    intptr_t i1 = p1;
    int *p2 = i1;
    intptr_t i2 = p2;
    assert(i1 == i2);
}

void f5(void) {
    int *p1 = &z[0];
    int *p2 = &z[1];
    intptr_t i1 = p1;
    intptr_t i2 = p2;
    assert(i1 < i2);
}
```

- Which of the functions invoke undefined (implementation-defined) behavior?
- Does anything change if using `void*` instead of `int*`? How about any other data type as the target of the pointer?
- Does anything change if I use explicit casts from from `int*` to `intptr_t` and back? (Asking since GCC warns about the casts.)
- Which `assert`s are guaranteed never to trigger?

Comment: An important thing to note is that if `p` is a pointer to the first byte of a `T`, there may generally exist a pointer `q` which would compare equal to `p`, but would point just past the end of whatever object happens to precede `*p` in memory, and which would not be usable to access `*p`.  Thus, nothing would forbid a capricious implementation from treating `(T*)(intptr_t)p` as a pointer (e.g. `q`) which equals `p` but cannot be dereferenced to access `*p`, and thus most code which would try to dereference a pointer produced by a round trip through `intptr_t` would invoke Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the C11 standard has to say about `intptr_t`:

> #### 7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers
>
> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
> intptr_t
> ```

And the same for `uintptr_t` (other than signed -> unsigned).

Also from "6.5.4p3 Cast operators":

> Conversions  that  involve  pointers,  other  than  where  permitted  by  the  constraints  of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast.

Where 6.5.16.1 doesn't mention assigning pointers to an integer type, and vice versa (other than a `0` constant). That means that you do need a cast when assigning, gcc just allows it as a compiler extension (And it doesn't compile at all with `-pedantic-errors`)

As for the exact value that is returned in these conversions, this is what the standard has to say:

> #### 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> p5
> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, [...]
>
> p6
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. [...]

---

The basic guarantee you have is:

```c
int x;
(int*) (void*) (intptr_t) (void*) &x == &x;
/* But the void* casts can be implicit */
(int*) (intptr_t) &x == &x;
```

And it's not necessary to cast to the same integer. E.g., the following can be true:

```c
int x;
(intptr_t) &x != (intptr_t) &x;
```

Adding casts where necessary, and turning your asserts into returns (since `assert(false)` is undefined behaviour), none of your functions have undefined behaviour,  but `f2`, `f4` and `f5` can be false. `f3` must be true, since the two integers must be different to convert to different pointers.

Comment: That answers my question perfectly, thanks! As a matter of curiosity, which version of GCC fails to compile my code with `-pedantic`? I checked with GCC 10.1.0, and it only produces warnings (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 foo.c`)

Comment: Although converting an `int *` directly to `intptr_t` does certainly produce an implementation-defined result, and, in principle, that does not forbid that `(intptr_t) &x != (intptr_t) &x` evaluates to 1, I think you would be very hard pressed to find an implementation defining the conversion in such a way that that is possible.  Note-well that "implementation defined" is still defined -- it's just not certain to be defined consistently across different implementations.  Undefined behavior, on the other hand, is an altogether different beast.

Comment: _`f3` must be true, since the two integers must be different to convert to different pointers_ Where does this follow from? Why there can't be a hypothetical implementation tracking provenance of integer values using something other than the value itself?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer We can definitely assume that `memcmp(i1, i2, sizeof i1) == 0` could be false. Or even that `(void*) +(intptr_t) (void*) &x` is might be implementation defined. But intptr -> pointer conversions seem to work on integer values, regardless of any non-value padding, as a footnote in §6.3.2.3 (pointers) mentions a "mapping function for converting [...] an integer to a pointer", not an object of an integer type to a pointer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Some early llvm -> jvm I was working on implemented the `ptrtoint` instruction by returning the index in a static array. That would have had `(intptr_t) &x != (intptr_t) &x` always be true.

Comment: Interesting, @Artyer.  So you're saying, I take it, that the result of each evaluation of `&x` would be stored at its own index in that array.  But did that implementation, then, ensure that `(int*) (void*) (intptr_t) (void*) &x == &x` always evaluates to 1, as you observe is required?  If not, then it was just broken, not distinctive.

Comment: @Artyer If I obtain an integer value by casting from `void*`, then construct another integer value from the first one bit-by-bit: like, if the least significant bit of the first value is `0`, set the least significant bit of the new value to `0`, otherwise set to `1` etc... Will casting from the new integer value to `void*` count as «converting **back** to pointer to `void`», or the new integer value won't count as obtained from casting from `void*` and the result of casting won't necessarily compare equal to original pointer? Assuming no padding bits.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: On segmented-mode 80386, pointers are 48 bits; there are no instructions to copy a pointer, but there are instructions to write the bottom 32 bits and to write the top 16 bits.  If `p` is a pointer held in a register and `puip` is the address of a `uintptr_t`, the fastest way to set `*upuip = (uintptr_t)p`, if equal pointers need not yield equal integers, would be to write the bottom 48 bits of `upuip` while leaving the top 16 bits unmodified.

Answer (score 2):

If `intptr_t` exists, then it is capable of holding a `void*` without data loss:

> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
>    intptr_t
> ```
>
> (§7.20.1.4p1)

However, if the pointer is not a pointer to void, all bets are off unless it is a null pointer:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type. (§6.3.2.3p5-6)

"Previously specified" are the conversions between `void*` and integer types, and the conversion of a null pointer *constant* to an integer type.

So a strictly correct program would need to interpose `void*` casts:

```
intptr_t i = (intptr_t)(void*)p;
T* p = (void*)i;
```

That's ok, because round-trip conversion between any object type and `void*` is guaranteed to be lossless:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

(The explicit `intptr_t` case in the first line is necessary because assignment does not implicitly cast from pointer to integer, although some compilers allow that as an extension. However, in C the assignment operations do implicitly convert between `void*` and other pointer types (§6.5.16.1p1, fourth bullet point).)

Note that "object type" excludes function pointers.

Also, the fact that the sequence `void*`→`intptr_t`→`void*` is results in a value equal to the original value does not imply that the sequence `intptr_t`→`void*`→`intptr_t` has the same property. While the conversion between pointers and integers is "intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment", that statement is in a footnote, so it is not normative. And anyway it is possible that the "addressing structure of the execution environment" permits multiple representations of the same address. (You don't have to look too far to find examples :-). )